# How do I force re-evaluation of a defvar?

Tags: interactive-development

Suppose I have an Emacs lisp buffer that contains:

```
(defvar foo 1)
```

If I call `eval-last-sexp` or `eval-buffer`, `foo` is bound to 1. If I then edit this buffer to:

```
(defvar foo 2)
```

`eval-last-sexp` and `eval-buffer` do not re-execute this line, so `foo` is still 1.

This is particularly challenging when there are multiple such statements and I have to track down which lines are not being re-evaluated.

I looked at just restarting Emacs and then `(require 'foo)`, but then I have to be careful to avoid loading any older .elc files.

How can I be absolutely, positively sure that the variables and functions defined in the current file are in the same state as loading code afresh in a new Emacs instance?

Comment: You cannot be "*absolutely, positively sure that Emacs is in a state that is the same as loading the code afresh in a new Emacs instance*" without doing just that. If you want to be sure *only* wrt this and other *global variables*, then you can remove their values using `makunbound` and then re-evaluate the code in the buffer.

Comment: Sure, side effects like (silly code) `(incf emacs-major-version)` I can live with happening repeatedly. I'm interested in hacking on code with lots of `defvar` forms.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As explained in other answers, evaluating a `defvar` form using `eval-last-sexp` does not reset the default value.

Instead, you can use `eval-defun` (bound to `C-M-x` in `emacs-lisp-mode` by default), which implements the behaviour you want as a special exception:

> If the current defun is actually a call to `defvar` or `defcustom`,
>   evaluating it this way resets the variable using its initial value
>   expression even if the variable already has some other value.
>   (Normally `defvar` and `defcustom` do not alter the value if there
>   already is one.)

---

If you need to evaluate the full contents of a buffer, you can write a function that walks the top-level forms in turn and calls `eval-defun` on each. Something like this should work:

```
(defun my/eval-buffer ()
  "Execute the current buffer as Lisp code.
Top-level forms are evaluated with `eval-defun' so that `defvar'
and `defcustom' forms reset their default values."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (not (eobp))
      (forward-sexp)
      (eval-defun nil))))
```

Comment: _This_ is the answer. No need for fake defvars or extra setqs. Just use `eval-defun` instead of `eval-last-sexp `. You can even write a function that calls `eval-defun` on every form in the buffer, and use it instead of `eval-buffer`.

Comment: @Malabarba This post falls far short of answering the question. Use `eval-defun` instead of `eval-last-sexp`, sure, but the difficulty is for `eval-buffer`.

Comment: @Gilles yes, you're right. I added a tentative implementation of @Malabara's idea of calling `eval-defun` on every top-level form in the buffer.

Comment: This approach does not seem to work if the `defvar` is not inside a `defun`. Example: `(progn (defvar foo "bar"))`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi indeed, it only works when the `defvar` is a top-level form. Do you have actual code in which a `defvar` is nested inside a `progn` form? I sometimes do things like this, but only for throw-away code, in which I can easily replace `defvar` by `setq` if needed...

Comment: I like `defvar` because I can see the documentation on doing `C-h v` but I also like how `setq` can be re-eval'd. So I ended up with a solution that has both, using a [modified version](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/340b7ce03dc8be2b9b1183cb72eca68d4d030bcb/elisp/defuns.el#L73-109) of [Jordon's solution](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2301/115) (as the latter breaks loading of `projectile`). I use `defvar-re` for [vars that I'd need to tweak a lot](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/340b7ce03dc8be2b9b1183cb72eca68d4d030bcb/setup-files/setup-verilog.el#L33-92).

Comment: @kaushalmodi The latter examples that you cite (variables storing regular expressions) look a lot like candidates for `defconst` (which is always re-evaluated). There's recently been a very enlightening post on this topic in [endless parentheses](http://endlessparentheses.com/what-s-a-defconst-and-why-you-should-use-it.html)

Comment: @Francesco That's a great point! I will do that and use `defconst` instead :)

Answer (score 6):

Like the other answers say, this is just the way defvar works, but you can get around it, this is elisp after all.

You can temporarily redefine how defvar works if you'd like and during that time, reload the packages you'd like to reset.

I wrote a macro where during the evaluation of the body, defvars values will always be reevaluated.

```
(defmacro my-fake-defvar (name value &rest _)
  "defvar impersonator that forces reeval."
  `(progn (setq ,name ,value)
          ',name))

(defmacro with-forced-defvar-eval (&rest body)
  "While evaluating, any defvars encountered are reevaluated"
  (declare (indent defun))
  (let ((dv-sym (make-symbol "old-defvar")))
    `(let ((,dv-sym (symbol-function 'defvar)))
       (unwind-protect
           (progn
             (fset 'defvar (symbol-function 'my-fake-defvar))
             ,@body)
         (fset 'defvar ,dv-sym)))))
```

### Example Usage:

### file_a.el

```
(defvar my-var 10)
```

### file_b.el

```
(with-forced-defvar-eval
  (load-file "file_a.el")
  (assert (= my-var 10))
  (setq my-var 11)
  (assert (= my-var 11)
  (load-file "file_a.el")
  (assert (= my-var 10))
```

**Note:** This this should only be used for the purpose of reevaluating defvars, as it just ignores docstrings when reevaluating. You can modify the macro to support re-evaluating that applies docstrings as well, but I will leave that up to you.

In your case you could do

```
(with-forced-defvar-eval (require 'some-package))
```

But know what those who write elisp do so expecting defvar to work as specified, it could be they use defvar to define and setq in some init function to specify the value, so you may end up nil'ing variables you don't intend but this is probably rare.

### Alternative Implementation

Using this you can just redefine defvar globally and control whether or not it will set the symbol's value to the INIT-VALUE arg even if the symbol is defined by changing the value of the new `defvar-always-reeval-values` symbol.

```
;; save the original defvar definition
(fset 'original-defvar (symbol-function 'defvar))

(defvar defvar-always-reeval-values nil
  "When non-nil, defvar will reevaluate the init-val arg even if the symbol is defined.")

(defmacro my-new-defvar (name &optional init-value docstring)
  "Like defvar, but when `defvar-always-reeval-values' is non-nil, it will set the symbol's value to INIT-VALUE even if the symbol is defined."
  `(progn
     (when defvar-always-reeval-values (condition-case nil
         (makunbound ',name)
       (error nil)))
     (original-defvar ,name ,init-value ,docstring)))

;; globally redefine defvar to the new form
(fset 'defvar (symbol-function 'my-new-defvar))
```

Comment: I'm not sure redefining the behaviour of `defvar` is a good idea: there are several different possible uses of `defvar`, with slightly different semantics. For example, one use your macro doesn't account for is the `(defvar SYMBOL)` form, which is used to tell the byte-compiler about the existence of a variable without setting a value.

Comment: If you absolutely need to redefine `defvar` with a macro, you would probably be better off prefixing the original `defvar` form with a `makunbound`, rather than replacing it by `setq`.

Comment: Yes, it is a terrible idea, and should only be used for things like reevaluting the defvars of a loaded package in your scratch buffer, you should never ship something like this.

Comment: @Francesco also you are right about the makunbound version, I had implemented that but strayed away from the idea, I have put that code on my answer as an alternative.

Comment: In case anyone runs across this answer and wonders _why_ `my-new-defvar` might crash your Emacs, it's because if the symbol being passed is already void (like from a fresh Emacs restart) and `makunbound` gets involved, it throws an error (and coincidentally crashed Emacs for me). Wrap the `makunbound` call in a `condition-case` to catch that error.

Answer (score 3):

The `defvar` is being evaluated and doing exactly what you've specified. However, `defvar` only sets an initial value:

> The optional argument INITVALUE is evaluated, and used to set SYMBOL,
>   only if SYMBOL's value is void.

So to achieve what you want you would either need to unbind the variable before re-evaluating, e.g.

```
(makunbound 'foo)
```

or use `setq` to set the value, e.g.

```
(defvar foo nil "My foo variable.")
(setq foo 1)
```

If you don't need to specify a docstring here you can skip the `defvar` altogether.

If you really want to use `defvar` and automatically unbind this, you will need to write a function to find `defvar` calls in the current buffer (or region, or last sexp, etc); call `makunbound` for each one; and then do the actual eval.

Comment: I was off playing with an `eval-buffer` wrapper that would unbind everything first, but @Francesco's answer about `eval-defun` is really what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The following macro was created by tracing `eval-defun` to its supporting functions and modifying it so that it is no longer necessary to evaluate a region of a particular buffer.  I needed help in the related thread [Converting an expression to a string](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33130/converting-an-expression-to-a-string), and @Tobias came to the rescue -- teaching me how to convert the imperfect function into a macro.  I don't think we need `eval-sexp-add-defvars` to precede `elisp--eval-defun-1`, but if someone thinks that is important, please let me know.

```lisp
;;; EXAMPLE:
;;;   (defvar-reevaluate
;;;     (defvar undo-auto--this-command-amalgamating "hello-world"
;;;     "My new doc-string."))

(defmacro defvar-reevaluate (input)
"Force reevaluation of defvar."
  (let* ((string (prin1-to-string input))
        (form (read string))
        (form (elisp--eval-defun-1 (macroexpand form))))
    form))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the line is not getting re-evaluated.  The problem is that `defvar` defines a variable and its *default value*.  If a variable already exists, then changing its default value does not modify the current value.  Unfortunately, I think you will need to run a `setq` for every variable whose value you wish to update.

This may be overkill, but you could update your file like this if you want to be able to easily update `foo` to its new default value.

```
(defvar foo 2)
(setq foo 2)
```

but that requires that you maintain the default value in two places in your code.  You could also do this:

```
(makunbound 'foo)
(defvar foo 2)
```

but if there is a chance that `foo` is declared elsewhere you may have some side effects to deal with.

Comment: That's difficult when trying to test changes to a complex mode. I'd rather not change the code. `eval-defun` treats `defvar` specially, so surely there's something similar for whole buffers?

Comment: @WilfredHughes I'm not sure what you mean by "something for whole buffers."  You want a single function that will `makunbound` any variables declared in the current buffer, and then re-evaluate it?  You could write your own, but I don't think that there is an out-of-the-box function for this. **EDIT:** Never mind, I get what you are saying. An `eval-defun` that works on the whole buffer.  It looks like @JordonBiondo has your solution for that.

Comment: No. The problem *is* lack of re-evaluation: `defvar` does nothing if the variable already has a value (as its doc says: `The optional argument INITVALUE is evaluated, and used to set SYMBOL, only if SYMBOL's value is void.`). The problem is **not** that `defvar` changes the default value and not the current value. `(defvar a 4) (default-value 'a) (setq a 2) (default-value 'a)`; then `C-x C-e` after the `defvar` sexp; then `(default-value 'a)`. `C-x C-e`, `eval-region`, and the like on a `defvar` sexp do **not** change the default value.