# Converting an expression to a string

Tags: defvar

I would like to add an alternative answer to the thread  [How do I force re-evaluation of a defvar?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-do-i-force-re-evaluation-of-a-defvar)  Before doing so, however, I would like to learn how to eliminate the single-quote to prevent evaluation of the argument INPUT to the new function `defvar-reevaluate`.  Perhaps I need a macro instead of a function ....?

**BEFORE**:

```lisp
(defun defvar-reevaluate (input)
"Force revelaution of a defvar."
  (let* ((string (prin1-to-string input))
         (form (read string))
         (form (elisp--eval-defun-1 (macroexpand form))))
    (eval form)))

(defvar-reevaluate
  '(defvar undo-auto--this-command-amalgamating "hello-world"
  "My new doc-string"))
```

**AFTER** -- without the single quote.

```lisp
(defvar-reevaluate
  (defvar undo-auto--this-command-amalgamating "hello-world"
  "My new doc-string"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a non-evaluated expression as argument without `quote` you have to use a macro since the arguments of (non-special) functions are evaluated before the function call.

`(quote a)` evaluates just to the un-evaluated expression `expr`. That's why `(quote expr)` works as argument.

Your code with the `defun` replaced by `defmacro` could look like the following demo.

```el
(defmacro defvar-reevaluate (input)
  "Force revelaution of a defvar."
  (let* ((string (prin1-to-string input))
     (form (read string))
     (form (eval-sexp-add-defvars (elisp--eval-defun-1 (macroexpand form)))))
    form))

(defvar-reevaluate
  (defvar undo-auto--this-command-amalgamating "hello-world"
    "My new doc-string"))
```

Note that the last `eval` from your `defun` is not required since the returned expression of the macro is evaluated at the call of `defvar-reevaluate`.